# Simple calculus question when n tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{n-2} = 1/e...??
$$

If so how..?

n to the power n-2. This is the formular cayleys theorem

I have tried but could not find it. Kindly help

Comment: Answer to this question: what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} n=?$

Comment: That's not the Cayley's theorem I know...

Comment: @SalechAlhasov:  lim n→∞ n^(n−2)

Comment: @Tyler: cayleys theorem is the number of labled trees of n vertices is n^(n-2)
I was trying to find the probability of a selected node to be leaf for a very large tree.

Answer (score 4):

for $n>3$, $n^{n-2}>n$, so the limit is clearly $+\infty$

Answer (score 3):

What I think you meant is
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n = 1/e.
$$

Comment: no.. my question is 
what is the solution for 
lim n→∞ n^(n−2)